# Can't run Android app on Android studio pops up Edit configuration

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I ve got this Android project built using Gradle with the output : `build successful`,Andthen that I imported the project to android studio.

Whenever I try to click on the green `run` button, it pops up me this error to 
"Edit the configuration"

[image]

Comment: It builds the gradle and THEN you import the project? That doesn't seem like the right order.

Comment: that's exactly what I did,should I import it with only with android studio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you do not have any configured Android app, just click on the arrow pointing downwards which is on the left of RUN button and click on Edit Configurations. This will open a new screen where you can add a new configuration, just like in we do in Eclipse.

Comment: Can you tell me what are these configurations ?

Comment: Do you have an emulator set up or are you using a real device?
You have to set that up

Comment: None !;I am setting up the emulator !

Comment: I clicked on Edit Configuration button ,this is how it looks like : http://i.imgur.com/vhUmj57.png

Comment: Click "..." next to prefer android device and create an emulator.
You may have to download an emulator with the sdk

Answer (score 0):

So the verison I was working is (on lunix) : v0.8.14

in order to fix this issue you should install this versio n :  0.9.3 on the Canary channel

download here : http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary

Answer (score 0):

Android studio 1.0 is released, try it this issue is fixed now.

Comment: Yeah , switching to v1